# PayPay Pay later messaging showing only for 6 Month not for 4 month on live production

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have added the paypal pay in 4 messaging on my website but only showing 6 month pay messaging.
and using sandbox sdk its showing proper pay in 4 message with installment amount.

[Six month payment message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjtYJ.png)

But need to show like below pay in 4 with installment amount.

[four month payment message with installment amount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t327U.png)

Need four month message with installment amount for live as well like sandbox.

Please suggests.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pay in 4 is not a "four month payment message", it is one payment every 2 weeks (across 2 months).  Those are two different offer types, and US customers may have both to choose from during their checkout.

If your [messaging integration is the same](https://www.paypal.com/ppcredit/messaging/customize?layout=text&device=message&logo-type=inline&text-color=black&country=US), contact PayPal to ask why the Pay in 4 offer isn't shown for the production account.